# How to process packets received from Https request in java?

Tags: java

Since packets received by making https request are in encrypted form. I wanna know how to decode them in java.

Comment: This question needs more context - firstly, how are you making this request, because typically you don't deal with HTTP packets, but something more like an `InputStream`.  And when you say "encrypted", who encrypted them and with what algorithm?

Comment: can you put some source code..?

Answer (score 3):

The communication is encrypted and decrypted for you by the HttpsURLConnection object. You don't have to deal with encryption and decryption yourself.

Comment: And you probably don't want to.

Comment: ya but i really need to read the packets since i need to process them. If i do new String(packet.data) for http Packet , its readable. But this is not same with https packets if i do the similar thing. I want them readable too